# Is it safe to use a laptop charger after plugging it to a power strip that caused a short circuit?

Tags: power-supply, lenovo-laptop

So for a while my charger would spark when connecting to this old power strip. I thought nothing of it, as I saw in here that sparks are a natural occurrence; but today, when I plugged it in, it made a small explosion or blast or whatever and short circuit the house. Clearly it was the strip, as you could smell something burning inside of it, and there were ash on the strip itself. It also took a really small chunk out of one of the pins.

So I cleaned the charger's pins from residual ash, plugged it in to the socket, and nothing bad happened.

Question is - is it safe now to plug it into the laptop? Even if it'll work, will it shorten the lifespan of my rig? Is it dangerous in any way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're now left with the dilemma… did it fail open, did it fail closed or did it not fail?

You might think that's a better-than-two-in-three chance you'll get away with it, but unless you want to test the odds by plugging it into your laptop to see if it survives, best bet would be to get a pro to check it over, or economically probably to just recycle that one & buy another.

Comment: Lets say, hypothetically, I were to plug said charger to the laptop. If it's faulty, will I see it right away?

Or is there a chance that the damage will be over time, slowly, without me noticing the fault

Comment: If it failed open or didn't fail, it is safe. Fail open it will not charge, of course. If it failed closed your laptop will start to smoke… that's when you'll know it wasn't worth the guess.

Comment: Update for future readers with same problem: The charger is okay and charging well! At least from first sight